# How to make a strike through text using DataBinding?

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a TextView and CheckBox, and I want it to work in such way:

- if checkBox is not checked, then set the text given
- if checkBox is checked, then make a strike through the text

If I was using ViewBinding I would write it like this:

```
binding.textViewName.paint.isStrikeThruText = task.completed
```

The problem is to set this strike using DataBinding.

Is there a way to do it using "pure" DataBingding or it is necessary to use some adapters?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom BindingAdapter as kotlin extension:

```
@BindingAdapter("strikeThrough")
fun TextView.strikeThrough(strikeThrough: Boolean = true) {
    this.paintFlags = this.paintFlags or
        if (strikeThrough) {
            Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
}
```

Usage in XML layout:

```xml
<TextView
  app:strikeThrough="@{true}"
.../>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to draw strikethrough text in XML. You'll need a BindingAdapter.

Or just go back to using view binding! The community has largely turned away from data binding.